# JavaScript Count Down timer not working in safari(apple devices) its working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
**in safari countdown not appearing, please check here http://ao-demo.com/sa**
```

```
**in safari countdown not appearing, please check here http://ao-demo.com/sa**
```

```
**in safari countdown not appearing, please check here http://ao-demo.com/sa**
```

```
**in safari countdown not appearing, please check here http://ao-demo.com/sa**
```

```
**in safari countdown not appearing, please check here http://ao-demo.com/sa**
```

```
jQuery('.count_timmer.dt').each(function() {
    var date_time = jQuery(this).attr('data-dt');
    var current_itme = jQuery(this);
    console.log(date_time);
    var arr = date_time.split(/[\-\+ :T]/);
    var countDownDate = new Date(arr[0], arr[1] - 1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
    console.log(countDownDate);
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        current_itme.find('.count.days .count_tag').html(days);
        current_itme.find('.count.hurs .count_tag').html(hours);
        current_itme.find('.count.min .count_tag').html(minutes);
        current_itme.find('.count.sec .count_tag').html(seconds);
        /* document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";*/
        // If the count down is finished, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            current_itme.hide();
            current_itme.parents('.future_content').find('.header_btns.bid-btn').show();
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also not working in Firefox. I get `Invalid Date`.

Why are you splitting your date? `new Date("10,30 2020 14:30:00")` is perfectly valid.

This also seems to make the timer work for me.

Comment: var arr = "2010-03-15 10:30:00".split(/[- :]/),
    date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
this part did the trick, and it's now working in apple devices, there was date formate issue before which was invalid date error in Apple devices, here is the link to live site where it is working great now, https://slymanauction.com/ and here is the screenshot to working code https://prnt.sc/tqhqen